# spring-mvc CassandraTemplate NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have some troubles with my pom.xml while working with spring-data-cassandra.

My pom.xml looks like -

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cassandra -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

My main controller class is something like below -

```
public String insertEmp(Locale locale, Model model, @ModelAttribute Employee emp) {
    logger.info("Create method in home controller", locale);

    String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    String keyspace = "jetset";

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoints(serverIP)
      .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

    CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate = new CassandraTemplate(session);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", "Test" );
    //employeeService.createEmployee(emp);
    cassandraTemplate.insert(emp);

    return "admin/index";
}
```

Now when i am running the program i am getting below error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:38) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.java:83) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:123) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:54) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:299) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:179) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:66) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.getTableName(CassandraTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:237) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:232) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.jetset.estate.HomeController.insertEmp(HomeController.java:91) ~[classes/:na]
```

This looks like a pom issue, but i am not able to figure it out.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

AJ

Comment: Please let me know if further code/details are needed, but the question is really urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it fixed.

I was choosing wrong spring distribution with spring-data-cassandra.

Switched to spring 3.2.8 and cassandra to 1.0.0 and issue was fixed.

Hope this helps some one else as well.